# Symfony routes in App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, symfony-1.4

Although we had some difficulties, we finally achieved to make our Symfony 1.4 application work fine in App Engine.

However, we are experiencing a problem related to the routes in Symfony.
From App Engine SDK (localhost) everything works perfect. If we access the URL:

```
http://localhost:9080/user/create
```

The parameters "user" and "create" are automatically detected by symfony as the "module" and "action" variables.

But when the application is deployed in App Engine, the same route `/user/create` does not work. Symfony shows an error message indicating that both the module and action parameters are empty.

Any idea of why these two environments have different behavior or how could it be fixed to get it work in the same way as in App Engine?

Comment: Please post the content of your __app.yaml__, it is likely a misconfigured handler.

Comment: # Workers

- url: /tasks/email
  script: workers/email.php
  
- url: /tasks/push
  script: workers/push.php
  
    
# Global redirect 

- url: /.*
  script: api.php

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know breaklines are not supported in comments. Actually, the **app.yaml** file is quite simple. A couple of workers and a rule to redirect all the requests to the script **api.php**.

Comment: This issue is most likely fixed in 1.9.0: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig#Updated_PHP_SELF